# Visualforce page not found error

Tags: apex, visualforce

Hi all I am working on a file upload using a vf page:
Details Attached

Vf page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="CustomQuoteTemplateController" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false">
 <head>
 <style type="text/css">
 body { font-family: Arial Unicode MS; }
 </style>
 </head>
 <h1>Quote Information</h1>
 <apex:panelGrid columns="1" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellPadding="5" width="100%">
 <apex:outputText value="{!Account.Name}" />
 <apex:outputText value="{!TODAY()}" />
 <apex:outputText value="{!Account.QuoteNumber__c}" />
 <apex:outputText value="{!Account.Name}" />
 <apex:outputText value="{!Account.Phone}" />
 <apex:outputText value="{!Account.Email__c}" /> 
 </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:page>
```

Apex class:

```
public with sharing class CustomQuoteTemplateController {
    public Account a {get;set;}
    public CustomQuoteTemplateController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { 
        a = (Account)controller.getRecord(); 
        a= [SELECT Name,QuoteNumber__c FROM Account WHERE ID = :a.Id];
        String quoteNum = a.QuoteNumber__c;
        String fileName = 'Quote_' +quoteNum + '.pdf';
        Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
    }
}
```

Test Class:

@isTest

```
public with sharing class CustomAccountTemplateControllerTest {
    @isTest static void CustomAccountTemplateControllerTest() {
        Account q = new Account(Name='123 Test', Opportunity__c='0065j00000naterAAA', Contact__c ='0035j00000bseRZAAY');
        insert q;
     
        Account qu = [SELECT Name, AccountNumber FROM Account WHERE Id =:q.Id];
        String fileName = 'Account_' + qu.Name + '.pdf';
        System.assertEquals('Account_123 Test.pdf', fileName);
        Test.StartTest(); 
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(q);
        CustomQuoteTemplateController testQuotePlan = new CustomQuoteTemplateController(sc);
        PageReference pageRef = Page.CustomQuoteTemplate; // Add your VF page Name here
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(q.Id));
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        Test.StopTest();
    }
}
```

I am receiving an error Page CustomQuoteTemplate does not exist. How do I fix this?

Also how can I improve the code coverage

Comment: Setting the current page reference does nothing whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be an issue if you can confirm that the Visualforce page actually deployed/saved correctly in your org. You may also need to confirm that the testing user has proper access to the visualforce page as well.

For code coverage, be sure that you follow testing best practices. The focus is NOT just code coverage. This article documents how to properly unit test well: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/07/six-tips-great-unit-tests

Every one of your test methods should be arranged in this way.

> 1. Arrange – Act – Assert
>    The three A’s are a good practice for unit tests on all platforms, but is even more important in Salesforce. Start by arranging anything you need for your test, including preparing test data. It’s often a good idea to pull this into a separate method, as it helps keep your test compact and easy to read. Next, you act, executing your business rules or logic against the things you’ve arranged. Finally, all good tests should assert their results to check the outcome. A test that does not assert the result is no test at all!